# How to remove all groups that contain a specific word Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, minecraft

I have a notepad++ file that has lots of groups in it containing the entry "spawn: 0" I want to look for all of the groups that contain that entry and remove the groups entirely.

Here is sample text below showing what I want to keep in my doucment and what I want to remove from my document.

`world_C:-117123:26:323196:
      stacks: Cave Spider:1;
      location: world_C:-117123:26:323196
      placedby: 1438b703-b91a-4fee-a853-db0d279c30d9
      spawns: 90`

I want to keep the ones that look like this one above

But I want to remove the ones that look like any of these below.

    `world_C:-201259:37:274108:
      spawns: 0
      stacks: Cave Spider:1;
      location: world_C:-201259:37:274108
    world_C:-201269:36:274092:
      stacks: Cave Spider:1;
      location: world_C:-201269:36:274092
      spawns: 0
    world_C:-7230:26:325504:
      location: world_C:-7230:26:325504
      spawns: 0
      stacks: Skeleton:1;
    world_C:-288294:32:34488:
      location: world_C:-288294:32:34488
      spawns: 0
      stacks: Zombie:1;
    world_C:183436:65:240637:
      location: world_C:183436:65:240637
      spawns: 0
      stacks: Spider:1;
    world_C:-277077:33:-151565:
      stacks: Cave Spider:1;
      location: world_C:-277077:33:-151565
      spawns: 0
    world_C:-277084:49:-151582:
      spawns: 0
      stacks: Skeleton:1;
      location: world_C:-277084:49:-1515821`

The outcome would be a document that does not contain any groups with the words "spawns: 0" in them.

Comment: Do you want to remove the entire section containing "spawn : 0" ?

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59909486/edit) and add sample text (not an image) and expected result.

Comment: I have edited my question and added sample text rather than an image and yes @Wander3r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h+world_C:(?:(?!^\h+world_C).)*spawns: 0\b.*?(?=^\h+world_C|\Z)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                       # beginning of line
  \h+                   # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  world_C:              # literally
  (?:                   # non capture group
    (?!^\h+world_C)     # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't world_C with onlyy spaces before
    .                   # any character
  )*                    # end group, may appear 0 or more times
  spawns: 0\b           # literally, the word boundary prevents matching 0123
  .*?                   # 0 or more any character, not greedy
  (?=                   # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    ^                   # beginning of line
     \h+                # 1 or more horizontal spaces
     world_C            # literally
    |                 # OR
     \Z                 # end of file
  )                     # end of lookahead
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: @JamezD: You're welcome, glad it helps, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)